# How can I do matrix with 1 column?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, matrices

I want to make a matrix with elements like in the image:[image]

How can I do this?

Thank  you!

Comment: `\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}` ?, using the `amsmath` package

Answer (score 17):

A column vector is just a matrix with one column (from a typesetting point of view ;-)), so just use one of the various `matrix` possibilities and typeset with `\\` to switch to the next row.

Of course, `mathmode` is needed for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
$
\begin{pmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \alpha_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\
\end{pmatrix}
\neq
\begin{Bmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \alpha_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\
\end{Bmatrix}
\neq
\begin{bmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \alpha_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\neq
\begin{vmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \alpha_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\
\end{vmatrix}
\neq
\begin{Vmatrix}
  \alpha_{1} \\
  \alpha_{2} \\
  \vdots \\
  \alpha_{m} \\
\end{Vmatrix}
$
\end{document}
```

Use `pmatrix` for parentheses, `Bmatrix` for braces and `bmatrix` for brackets, `vmatrix` for single vertical lines, `Vmatrix` for doubled vertical lines.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Because this is typical non-LaTeX specific question (because this is question of type: give me a code, I don't want to think about it), I can reply: use simply `\pmatrix` or `\matrix`.

**Edit** The result exactly the same as in the answer above can be accomplished by the code:

```
\def\mmatrix#1#2#3{\left#1\matrix{#2}\right#3}
$$
  \pmatrix    {\alpha_1 \cr \alpha_2 \cr \vdots \cr \alpha_m}    \neq
  \mmatrix \{ {\alpha_1 \cr \alpha_2 \cr \vdots \cr \alpha_m} \} \neq
  \mmatrix [  {\alpha_1 \cr \alpha_2 \cr \vdots \cr \alpha_m}  ] \neq
  \mmatrix |  {\alpha_1 \cr \alpha_2 \cr \vdots \cr \alpha_m}  | \neq
  \mmatrix \| {\alpha_1 \cr \alpha_2 \cr \vdots \cr \alpha_m} \|
$$
\bye
```